# Service worker not listening to the action when the toolbar icon is clicked - Chrome Extension v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-action

I am new to this.

I have a requirement, which should open a new tab when clicked on the toolbar icon.

My manifest file :

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "description": "App",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      }
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {},
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["static/*"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "background"],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

And my `background.js` file

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"),
    active: true,
  });
});
```

This code currently opens a new tab only one time, and after that the service worker becomes inactive. After reloading the extension only I can open the new tab. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It's a bug, https://crbug.com/1316588.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to fix this by downgrading to manifest version 2.

My `manifest.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "description": "App",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      }
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {},
  "web_accessible_resources": ["static/*"],
  "permissions": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

And my `background.js` file looks like this :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL("index.html"),
    selected: true,
  });
});
```

I referred to daily.dev's [source code](https://github.com/dailydotdev/apps/blob/master/packages/extension/src/manifest.json) and fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this Chrome bug affects you:

> Issue [1316588](https://crbug.com/1316588): browserAction not getting dispatched when extension button clicked